# use (r, c) format for average formula with non-contiguous cells

Tags: excel, vba, function

[image: Here is a screenshot of my data:]

This is my code:

```
Sub sumavg()

With Worksheets(datasummary)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
j = 20

    For i = 1 To 30
        For j = 20 To 25
        Cells(5 * i - 2, j).Value = Average(A(5 * i - 2), G(5 * i - 2), M(5 * i - 2))
        Next j
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

I am struggling with the syntax for the AVERAGE formula. This is my first attempt at using formulae in macro. If possible, I would like to use the `(r, c)` format for the cell addresses, but haven't been able to find anything like that so far. I want to average the values in every 6th cell in row 3 and print it to T3. This process needs to be looped through 6 times for each block, and for 40 blocks.
At the moment this code is returning a "sub or function not defined" error, and highlighting the column indentifiers in the average formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub sumavg()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With Worksheets("datasummary")
        For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 5
            For j = 1 To 5
                .Rows(i + 2).Range("T1:Y2").Value = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(RC[-19],RC[-13],RC[-7]),""N/A"")"
            Next
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution gives me a runtime error saying unable to get average property of worksheet function.

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/fulltest_1) Atm I'm having trouble printing the AOIentries values. I got it working earlier today, but it's not working now. not sure if that's gonna be a problem for you, but if so just delete the If statement where the dict key is defined in module 4.

Comment: I should clarify that, while it is giving this run-time error, it is actually printing values where it should. Is this perhaps because it is dividing non-existant values by 0 when it comes to the transfer blocks?

Comment: @shecodes I ended up having to use R1C1 formulas to make it work.  I added an `IFERROR` to return `N/A` if the cells were all empty.

Comment: @shecodes are you allowed to use user defined classes for your assignment?

Comment: I don't anticipate that there will be any cases where all three values in the formula would be empty, although right now I can't get the macros to print the values for the transfer blocks when I copy/paste data from a different file that does include transfer blocks. I think it's a problem with the dictionary object. I don't see any reason why user-defined classes would be a problem.

Comment: @shecodes I put together a sample workbook showing how you can use a user defined class to simplify things:[UDClass.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2xu8wrolkkfmt5/DeleteFilteredRows.xlsm?dl=0).  I used my own data to show you some techniques.  Basically the each class is stored in a collection by is unique ID.  Each class holds the data for its ID and prints the details of its data to the report.

Comment: what was your code for the IFError statement? turns out there are cases where all 3 cells are blank :(

Comment: @shecodes Do you mean `"=IFERROR(AVERAGE(RC[-19],RC[-13],RC[-7]),""N/A"")"`??

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the edited version of your answer. I actually went ahead with your original code cos I solved my other issues. And it's working perfectly except when all three cells are blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub sumavg()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <~~ double-quotes
    For i = 1 To 30
      For j = 20 To 25
       .Cells(5 * i - 3, j).Value = Application.Average( _
        Application.Union( _
          .Range("A" & (5 * i - 3)), .Range("G" & (5 * i - 3)), .Range("M" & (5 * i - 3)) _
        ))
      Next j
    Next i

  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. Now however, I need to change the column references to a formula that changes according to j, which is why I want to use the (r, c) format. so it would be something like `.Range((5 * i - 2), (j - 19)), .Range((5 * i - 2), (j - 13)), .Range((5 * i - 2), (j - 7)) _
        ))`

Comment: @shecodes to use (r, c) you can simply replace `.Range("...")` with `.Cells(r, c)`.

Answer (score 1):

A.S.H's answer will get you what you want, but this will be much faster...

It's faster for 3 reasons:

1. Reading from individual cells is slow. It's faster to load all of the cells into a Variant array, and then work with the array.
2. Writing individual cells is slow. It's faster to minimize the number of times we write to cells, so I load the results into 1x6 arrays and insert them at the target locations.
3. Using `Application.Average` is a legacy syntax from Excel 95. It is faster to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average`, *and* you get Intellisense and a strongly typed result for free.

NB. You could probably avoid using the `Average` function (and eek out a little more performance) and calculate the result in memory, as this is a simple average with only 3 inputs, so you could use:

```
    'Calculate the average ourselves
    rowresults(1, colCounter) = (values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter) + values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter + 6) + values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter + 12)) / 3
```

Code:

```
Sub sumavg()
  Dim rowCounter As Long
  Dim colCounter As Long

  Dim values() As Variant

  Const START_COL As Long = 1
  Const END_COL As Long = 6

  Const OUTPUT_COL_START As Long = 20

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Load the values into an array - reading them this way is much faster than cell-by-cell
    values = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(150, 18)).Value
    For rowCounter = 1 To 30
      ReDim rowresults(1 To 1, START_COL To END_COL)
      For colCounter = START_COL To END_COL
        'Use Application.WorksheetFunction.Average to get Intellisense and a strongly typed Double result
        rowresults(1, colCounter) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter), values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter + 6), values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter + 12))

      Next colCounter
      'Write the entire row of results at once - 6 times faster than writing individual cells
      .Range(.Cells(5 * rowCounter - 2, OUTPUT_COL_START), .Cells(5 * rowCounter - 2, OUTPUT_COL_START + END_COL - START_COL)).Value = rowresults
    Next rowCounter
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ThunderFrame. Have a look at Thomas Inzina's answer - he has managed to anticipate that I also want to perform the same averaging task on the rows below the ones I'm currently working on. I have tried your solution and it works well, so now I have tried copy-pasting the `For colCounter` loop, changing all cases of `rowCounter - 2` to `rowCounter - 1`. What else needs to change, because it's throwing an error on the print line just before `Next rowCounter`. If you can tell me this, I will mark this answer as accepted.