# my average function is counting blank cells as 0

Tags: excel, vba, function

As far as I know, Excel Average functions do not include cells that are blank. However, my this appears to be exactly what my code is doing:

```
Sub sumavg()
  Dim rowCounter As Long
  Dim colCounter As Long

  Dim values() As Variant

  Const START_COL As Long = 1
  Const END_COL As Long = 6

  Const OUTPUT_COL_START As Long = 20

  With Worksheets("datasummary")
    'Load the values into an array
    values = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(199, 18)).Value
    For rowCounter = 1 To 40
      ReDim rowresults(1 To 1, START_COL To END_COL)
      For colCounter = START_COL To END_COL
'find average of AOIentries values
        rowresults(1, colCounter) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter), values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter + 6), values((5 * rowCounter - 2), colCounter + 12))

      Next colCounter
'print row of results
      .Range(.Cells(5 * rowCounter - 2, OUTPUT_COL_START), .Cells(5 * rowCounter - 2, OUTPUT_COL_START + END_COL - START_COL)).Value = rowresults
    
        For colCounter = START_COL To END_COL
'find average of RT values
        rowresults(1, colCounter) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(values((5 * rowCounter - 1), colCounter), values((5 * rowCounter - 1), colCounter + 6), values((5 * rowCounter - 1), colCounter + 12))

      Next colCounter
'print row of results
      .Range(.Cells(5 * rowCounter - 1, OUTPUT_COL_START), .Cells(5 * rowCounter - 1, OUTPUT_COL_START + END_COL - START_COL)).Value = rowresults

    Next rowCounter

  End With
End Sub
```

Here is the code to print values including blank cells:

```
For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        If d(r, 19) = 1 Then
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)    'get count
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r
Call createsummarytable
Call PopSummaryAOI(dBT)

dBT.RemoveAll

   For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = d(r, COL_RT)
    Next r
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the data the average function works on]

As far as I can tell, the cell is entirely blank, so it shouldn't be included in the average, but (20 + 17)/2 =/= 12.33, whereas (20 + 17 + 0)/3 = 12.33.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(199, 18)).Value`, you end up with an array of `Variant`.  `WorksheetFunction.Average` treats `Range`s and `Variant` arrays differently than it treats `Variant`s.  If you give it individual `Variant` for arguments, it casts them to `Double`s, and casting `Empty` to a `Double` results in 0.  If you want it to ignore empty cells, you need to pass it a `Range` or a `Variant()`:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim test As Variant
    test = Empty    'This is what you get from an EmptyCell.Value
    Debug.Print CDbl(test)  'Prints 0.
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Average(test, 0, 10)  'Prints 3.33333333333333.
    Range("A1").ClearContents   'Nothing in A1 now.
    Debug.Print Range("A1").Value = Empty   'Prints True
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("A1"), 0, 10)   'Prints 5
End Sub
```

Comment: If you define `test` as a `Variant` array with 3 elements (Empty,0,10), `WorksheetFunction.Average(test)` returns 5, so `Average` behaviour is not consistent.

Comment: @BrakNicku - The OP is passing individual `Variant` values, not the `Variant()`. Updated.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - LOL.  Changed the ping.

Comment: I guess she should have used my answer to [use (r, c) format for average formula with non-contiguous cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732671/use-r-c-format-for-average-formula-with-non-contiguous-cells) instead of ThunderFrame's...lol

Comment: @ThomasInzina - Yup.  Fast is good when it works.  Not when it doesn't.

Comment: @Comintern nice explanation and example